# htlatex for multilingual text and output to odt format

Tags: cjk, make4ht, chinese

I have an elaborate workflow for producing academic articles that produced latex wit references processed using Biblatex-chicago. The text is mainly in English, but occasionally I need to include excerpts in other languages, including Chinese.

I use htlatex because I usually need to provide drafts in word format. I use make4ht to create odt files, then open them in word and save in docx format, which is what editors and readers require.

When it comes to Chinese characters, it all works fine for pdf, and I have now also got htlatex/make4ht to produce Chinese properly for html files, by following the instructions in the answer to this question:

[How to create multilingual (English, Japanese) html document with htlatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275352/how-to-create-multilingual-english-japanese-html-document-with-htlatex)

However, I can't get the process to work for odt format. When I process the files everything is fine except the Chinese characters are completely absent. As far as I can tell they are not producing any output that is not being displayed, they are just absent.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
\altusepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{STFangsong}
\setCJKsansfont{STFangsong}
\setCJKmonofont{STFangsong}
\setCJKmathfont{STFangsong}
\altusepackage{xunicode}
\begin{document}
中文\\
This section is in english.
\end{document}
```

I don't really care about formatting for this purpose, so I just used a single font for simplicity. This is the command I've been using to compile:

```
make4ht -f odt -m draft -ue mybuild.mk4 test.tex
```

I'll be very grateful if anyone can help me to work out how to make this work! I'm very much a dabbler so may well be overlooking something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\ifdefined\HCode\else
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{STFangsong}
\setCJKsansfont{STFangsong}
\setCJKmonofont{STFangsong}
\setCJKmathfont{STFangsong}
\altusepackage{xunicode}
\fi
\begin{document}
中文\\
This section is in english.
\end{document}
```

I've used `\ifdefined\HCode` to suppress loading of `xeCJK` and `xunicode` packages when you compile the document with `make4ht`. They are not needed.

This document can be compiled using

```
make4ht -lm draft -e mybuild.mk4 test.tex
```

Note that the recent versions of `make4ht` use `utf-8` output by default, so it is not necessary to use the `-e` option. What is necessary though is to use the `-l` option to require compilation with LuaTeX. This enables the support for full Unicode.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: As usual excellent suggestion....

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply!

Comment: This works for my MWE, but I'm having problems with my actual files. The process I'm using creates a main file with the text and stitches a whole tex file together with \input. That is not compiling using the method above. However, when I manually copy all the pieces into one file, so that \input is not required, then it works fine. Is it that ht4latex can't work with included files? If so do you know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: sorry I mean 'tex4ht'!

Comment: PS - it might be that some of the included files are in texmf instead of in the working directory, but when compiling to html, it works no problem.

Comment: @JonMair `\input` should work. Maybe the issue can be that the input filename contains spaces or special characters? (I don't think it should matter)

Comment: Thanks -- there was a hyphen in the filename, but I removed it and still had the same problem. When I put everything in one file it works fine, when I use the original bundle of files I get the following error:

Comment: @JonMair I think the error message was truncated from your message :)

Comment: Sorry, it's here: https://pastebin.com/JSNKWFRh

Comment: I found a way of getting it to work: I commented out the fontspec command. Will I need that at some point? It seems to work without it for pdf, html and odt.

Comment: @JonMair  do you use current TeX Live? I can see there is also some issue with Biblatex in your log file. I think I solved similar issue some time ago.

Comment: Yes I'm using the 2020 distribution of TeX Live. The bib latex issues don't seem to affect the output at the moment, but I'd be grateful if you could point me to any info on that too.

Comment: @JonMair I think I will need a complete example. The Biblatex issue can eb something new, but it really depends on packages you use.

Comment: just to say apologies for not replying to this sooner, in the middle of exam marking!

Comment: @JonMair no problem :)